My very young mandarin orange is loosing its last leaf and drying out. Is there hope?
My 5 month old mandarin orange (citrus reticulata) has lost two of its three leaves and is currently loosing its last one. But the stem is still green. Can I still save it? And if yes, how?
I planted many seeds in April and three young plants sprouted. They grew perfectly without a worry, but from 4.-15.7. I was on vacation and forgot to put them out of the direct sunlight from my window and in addition to that they weren't watered during that time. When I came back all three young plants had their leaves hanging. I watered all three of them immediately. The smallest one died during the the following week, while the biggest one bounced back and looks perfectly fine. The middle one (which I'm concerned about here) has slowly lost two of its three leaves, after they dried out and is currently loosing its third and last leaf. The stem is still green though and because the plant has survived for almost two month now, I'm hoping that it can still be saved.
Does anyone know what I can do to save it? Should I remove the dried out leaf and dry top of the stem?
FYI: Two weeks ago I put it in a seperate pot from the bigger plant, so that they don't compete for resources. Its pot has working drainage and I take care not to water it when the soil is still wet. And of course I have taken it out of the direct sunlight. For three weeks now I started fertilising it together with my other plants once weekly(as instructed) with a liquid fertilizer.
Pictures:

The plant I'm concerned about.
The bigger plant that survived and is well with the exact same treatment.




the soil looks extremely wet...is it?

@JosephWit Luis R. answered in an answer: "yes, if I remember correctly I watered the plant shortly before taking the picture. Otherwise I take care not to water the plant, if the earth is still wet 1-2 cm beneath the surface."

Oh dear... the small one is pretty much screwed. If there aren't still any buds on the part that's still alive, all hope is lost - bin it. The large one, on the other hand is positively thriving - keep it going and you'll have a nice little tree there.

+1, just a footnote: do perform a post mortem on the small tree as to protect the large one from same fate later on.
